# Android Marshmallow new permission support

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

Must I declare all the permissions in the Manifest as before?

I'm asking it for a reason - let's have a scenario that you introduce a new feature to your app that requires the Contacts permission, and let's think about it from a product perspective.

When it comes to Marshmallow users, everything will be okay (concerning UX) - upon update, they won't ask for new permissions, but only the moment of need. That's fine with me.

But, prior Marshmallow users will be requested for the new permission upon update, and may disapprove it, and by that, won't update the app. Not good.

What if I want my new feature to be available only for Marshmallow users and above, while older versions users won't get the feature and be asked for the new permission upon update? Can I do something like this?

Hope I was clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Must I declare all the permissions in the Manifest as before?

They must be in the manifest, yes.

> What if I want my new feature to be available only for Marshmallow users and above, while older versions users won't get the feature and be asked for the new permission upon update? Can I do something like this?

Yes. Use [the awkwardly-named `<uses-permission-sdk-23>` element](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-sdk-23-element.html) as a replacement for `<uses-permission>`. On API Level 22 and older devices, this element will be ignored. On API Level 23+ devices, you can request the permission at runtime as normal.

Comment: Sounds great. Thanks!